# Use two results from a table as two aliases in left-joined query

Tags: mysql

Not sure how to word this properly but I'll give it a go.

I have two tables: users and fields_values

users has an id
fields_values has item_id (which is user_id), field_id and value

If possible I want the list of users, the value of the field with field_id of x for that user as "employee_id" and the value of the field with field_id of y for that user as "location".

So like this

```
USERS           FIELDS
------------   ----------------------------
id   | Name     field_id | item_id  | value
------------   ----------------------------
448  | Karen     1       |  448     | 1234
489  | Steve     2       |  448     | bathurst
                 1       |  489     | 2234
                 2       |  489     | orange

RESULTS
USER
  0 ==>
  id: 448
  employee_id: 1234
  location: bathurst

  1 ==>
  id: 489
  employee_id: 2234
  location: orange
```

Comment: There is no `id` field in your `field_values` table. Do you mean `field_id`?

Comment: field_id is the id of the field.

Comment: Please can you post your table schemas, sample data.

Comment: @fubar I did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do what you want. You need to join to the `fields_values` tables twice, once to get the `employee_id` and once to get the `location`. I've used `LEFT JOIN` to guard for the case where a user may not have an `employee_id` or `location`, if this cannot be the case you can use a straight `JOIN`. Replace the values of `x` and `y` in this query as you need.

```
SELECT u.id, fv1.value AS employee_id, fv2.value AS location
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN fields_values fv1 ON fv1.item_id = u.id AND fv1.field_id = x
LEFT JOIN fields_values fv2 ON fv2.item_id = u.id AND fv2.field_id = y
```

Comment: This is the answer thankyou. Because I'm using a form builder on Joomla though it's not exactly how it ended up for me but close enough

`SELECT user.id AS user.id, field1.value AS user.employee_id, field2.value AS user.location FROM #_users AS user LEFT JOIN #_fields_values AS field1 ON user.id = field1.item_id LEFT JOIN #_fields_values AS field2 ON user.id = field2.item_id WHERE field1.field_id = '1' AND field2.field_id = '2' LIMIT 100;`